# How to update directives based on service changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-directive

I have a directive(`parent-directive`) containing a slider(mySlider), that on `stop` event, call an angular `$resource` service with 2 params and the service return an object.
Directives structure:

```
<parent-directive>
<div ui-slider="slider.options" ng-model="mySlider" id="my-slider">
<span child-directive-one></span>
<span child-directive-two></span>
<span child-directive-three></span>
<div>
    <span child-directive-four></child-directive-four>
</div>
</parent-directive
```

Whenever the user drag the slider, the service is called with different params and retieve new result, based on it I need to update the child directives.

I have in mind three ways:

1. using ng-model for all child elements instead directives, binding them on the scope of a controller in `parent-directive`;
2. the second one, that I don't know how to do it, is to create a controller in the `parent-directive`, that send and receive data from the service and share it to `child-directives` in order to update them.
3. the last one is to to create a state variable in the service and update it using a controller like to point 1.(see it above) and use a $watch to supervise the variable state and when it's changed then update the `child-directives`.

How should I proceed?

Please have a look here to see a brief code:
http://jsfiddle.net/v5xL0dg9/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `ngModel` is intended for two way binding, i.e. controls that allow the user to interfere with the value. From the description, it seems they are display-only components. So I would advise against using the `ngModel`.
2. Normally child directives require their parent. This allows them to call methods on the parent controller. What you need is the opposite: the parent controller needs to call methods on the children. It can be done: the children call a `registerChild()` method, and the parent iterates all registered children when it needs to call them. I find this implementation cumbersome.
3. Services are globals/singletons. I would vote against tying the service implementation to the UI needs.

My advice looks like your implementation of option 3, but with the parent controller holding the data:

1) Place the data you want to share with the child directives in a member variable of the parent controller:

```
myApp.directive('parentDirective', ['myService', function(myService){
    ...
    controller: function($scope) {
        ...
        this.sharedThing = ...;
    }
}]);
```

The `sharedThing` can be updated when the service returns new data, or any other time it is necessary.

2) Have the children require the parent (just like your option 2), and *watch* this property:

```
myApp.directive('childDirectiveOne', function() {
    return {
        ...
        require: 'parentDirective',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, parentDirective) {
            scope.$watch(
                function() {
                    return parentDirective.sharedThing;
                },
                function(newval) {
                    // do something with the new value; most probably
                    // you want to place it in the scope
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Depending on the nature of the data, a deep watch may be required.

Comment: .I implemented it like you suggested but I have 6 child-directives and it means 6 $watch methods(the service returns an obj with 6 properties and I used them one by one in the 6 child-directives). For better performens should I set a state variable and an object variable on the ctrl to share it with the directives? Asking in the directives to watch only the state variable? But I think this will not work. What do you think? Here is the code made on your sugestion: http://jsfiddle.net/8hkxv85x/1/

Comment: Is this block being repeated tens of times? If not, a few extra watches should not affect performance. If the actual logic is as simple as that of the fiddle, then I would also consider making the child directives with isolated scope, passing the data in a `'='` attribute and having the template bind to that scope property (it also creates a watch under the hoods).

Comment: thank you for the answer, why should I make the child directives with isolated scopes, passing data in a "=" attribute? I'm really new in angular and I learned that you do that only when you want to get things from the parent DOM in your directive. Thanks again! :)

Comment: The isolated scope is a formal way of passing data to a directive, without it relying on a specific parent scope.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see in my case how should I use "=", maybe an empty object like scope : {} it's enough. If I use "=" that's mean to add also an attribute in DOM. I feel I'm goofy, I can't get it(12h in angular only today it's blocking my mind :)  ) Thanks!